# Box option how to create this like Telegram

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]

How do I design like this (options box) when I click on a message in my application, please write the XML part

Can it be a card View that carries several elements?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It can be a cardview.
Here is the .xml code for each item in the list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_time"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time"
                android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can work on the aesthetics. I have just added a 'Time' icon and text "Time" as an example.

Then add a RecyclerView in your Activity layout and create an Adapter with the above layout for each item in the list. Lastly, set the RecyclerView to that adapter.

Comment: how to bubble open when click message like telegram ?